# Зациклить анимацию

Tags: jquery, css3

Доброго времени суток.
Подскажите пожалуйста как зациклить анимацию. Имеется анимация на css3

```
 $(".banner_text").addClass('animated fadeOutLeft');
 $(".banner_img").addClass('animated fadeOutRight');
```

Пытался через setTimeout вызывать вторую функцию в которой соответственно возвращал блоки на место. но после 1 круга цикл не идеи. Понимаю что вопрос вообщем то туповат.. но и я только учусь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, вам нужно [animation-iteration-count: infinite](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_animation-iteration-count.asp)?
Или, возможно, [setInterval](http://javascript.ru/setinterval)?